# Can I convert RELAX NG to the XSD?

Tags: java, xsd, relaxng

See subject: and if I can, my second question is, How? I tried to use the [*trang*](http://www.thaiopensource.com/relaxng/trang.html) Java library and nothing happened :(

Comment: Also note [*trang* on Github](https://github.com/relaxng/jing-trang) instead of the project's older homepage.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Trang works, try again.

The correct command line is:

```
java -jar trang.jar -I rnc -O xsd test.rnc test.xsd
```

Comment: I used next command:
java -jar trang.jar -I rnc -O xsd -i test.rnc -o test.xsd
and received next error:
fatal: at least two arguments are required
Trang version 20081028
usage: java com.thaiopensource.relaxng.translate.Driver [-I rng|rnc|dtd|xml] [-O rng|rnc|dtd|xsd] [-i input-param] [-o output-param] inputFileOrUri ... outputFile

Comment: @jitm - the command-line arguments you used don't match the syntax as described by the error message!